# Serializer complains about no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django

I'm running a Django query against the following table and I want to convert the resulting queryset to JSON:

```
class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city_ascii = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lat = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    lng = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country_abbrev2 = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    country_abbrev3 = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The query is trying to get a list of all of the cities in a given country 'country_abbrev' (without any duplicates):

```
cities = City.objects.filter(country_abbrev2=country_abbrev).values('city').distinct()
cities_json = serializers.serialize('json', cities)
return HttpResponse(cities_json, content_type='application/json')
```

The query returns this error:

```
Error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Now this other query does work but it returns the 'model' and 'pk' fields in addition to the 'city' field and I don't want them.

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', City.objects.filter(country_abbrev2=country_abbrev).distinct(), fields=('city'))
return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Is there a way to fix the first query?  Or is there a better way to do it?  This query is in an API view and I really would like to just pass an array of values like ```['city1', 'city2', ... ] that my JavaScript can parse on the client side.

Comment: Why do you need a serializer if the only thing from queryset you're using is city name? You can simply dump dictionary to json using;

Answer (score 0):

The serializer expects a common queryset like so:

```
cities = City.objects.filter(country_abbrev2=country_abbrev).only('city').distinct()
```

which translates the serializer to

```
cities_json = serializers.serialize('json', cities, fields=('city'))
```